# Python - Put factors of a number into an array in sorted order

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, factors

I have written this algorithm that finds all factors of a given number and puts them into a list:

```
def find_all_factors(n):
    factors = []
    for i in range(1, floor(sqrt(n))+1):
        if n % i == 0:
            factors.append(i)
            cofactor = n // i
            if i != cofactor: factors.append(cofactor)
    return factors
```

Inside the list cofactors will be placed next to eachother, but I would like them to appear in sorted order instead. Example of output from algorithm above: for `n = 36` it outputs `[1, 36, 2, 18, 3, 12, 4, 9, 6]`. I'm doing this as an exercise and I would like to know what the most efficient way of getting them in sorted order would be, any ideas?

You can see one of my solutions below. It works, but I don't think it's optimal.

```
def find_all_factors(n):
    lower_factors = []
    higher_factors = []
    for i in range(1, floor(sqrt(n))+1):
        if n % i == 0:
            lower_factors.append(i)
            cofactor = n // i
            if i != cofactor: higher_factors.append(cofactor)
    return lower_factors + [higher_factors[-i] for i in range(1, len(higher_factors)+1)]  #Reverses higher_factors.
```

Comment: Since it's an exercise I would like to have the sorting as part of the algorithm and not rely on running a separate sorting algorithm.

Comment: I asked for the most efficient way of getting the factors in sorted order, and adding a O(nlog(n)) sorting algorithm to the end of it is certainly not the most efficient way.

Comment: I think it's near optimal ( O sqrt(n) complexity )  with basic python tools.

Answer (score 1):

Just simply return the sorted list:

```
return sorted(factors)
```

how ever if you dont like using `sorted` function simply change for loop range to (1,n+1) :

```
def find_all_factors(n):
    factors = []
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        if n % i == 0:
            factors.append(i)
    return factors

find_all_factors(12) # [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 12]
```

another way is using `bisect`(most efficient way):

```
import bisect
def find_all_factors(n):
    factors = []
    for i in range(1, math.floor(math.sqrt(n))+1):
        if n % i == 0:
            bisect.insort(factors,i)
            cofactor = n // i
            if i != cofactor: bisect.insort(factors, cofactor)
    return factors

find_all_factors(12) # [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 12]
```

Insert in this module is `O(n)` however search is `O(log(n))`

Answer (score 1):

The one thing you are missing is simpler and easier operations on your lists. There is a Python built-in for reversing a sequence: [`reversed`.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=reversed#reversed)

So you can do:

```
return lower_factors + list(reversed(higher_factors))
```

Comment: That will result in a runtime error since you are trying to concatenate a list with an iterator. You would have to convert the iterator to a list, like so: list(reversed(higher_factors)).

Answer (score 0):

```
from math import floor, sqrt


def find_all_factors(n):
    factors = []
    for i in xrange(1, int(floor(sqrt(n)))+1):
        quotient, remainder = divmod(n, i)
        if remainder == 0:
            factors.append(i)
            if quotient not in factors:
                factors.append(quotient)
    return sorted(factors)

print find_all_factors(36)
```

output:`[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 9, 12, 18, 36]`